# Trying to scrape text when the tags and class name are exactly the same BS4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to grab the text from these two elements but the tags and class names are identical. The only difference between them is reactID and aria label. Im using bs4 and requests. This is my first stack overflow question so bear with me.

```
<td colspan="" class="Va(m) Ta(end) Pstart(20px) Fw(600) Fz(s)" aria-label="Change" data-reactid="85"> 

<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(600) C($positiveColor)" data-reactid="86">+2.28</span></td>

<td colspan="" class="Va(m) Ta(end) Pstart(20px) Fw(600) Fz(s)" aria-label="% Change" data-reactid="87"> 

<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(600) C($positiveColor)" data-reactid="88">+71.23%</span></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate the `<td>`'s by `data-reactid`.

```
el = soup.find('td', {'data-reactid': '85'})
el2 = soup.find('td', {'data-reactid': '87'})

el.text
el2.text
#+2.28
#+71.23%
```

Comment: Thank you! Gonna use the same method but with the aria-label attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find('tag_name', {'attr_name': 'attr_value'})` to scrape them. For your case it will look something like below:

```
# assuming scrap_me is bs4 obj
data1 = scrap_me.find('span', {'data-reactid': '86'})
data2 = scrap_me.find('span', {'data-reactid': '88'})
```